# How to show that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(n+1)^{n-1}}{n^n} =0$?

Tags: calculus, limits

I know the answer. It's $0$. But how would I get there?

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(n+1)^{n-1}}{n^n}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(n+1)^{n-1}}{n^n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n+1}\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1{n+1}\cdot\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n=0\cdot e = 0.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** use the binomial expansion to get the first few terms (the ones with the highest exponents) of the numerator. Then take the limit of each of the terms.

Answer (score 0):

Note $\frac{(n+1)^{n-1}}{n^n} = \frac{1}{n+1} \frac{(n+1)^n}{n^n}= \frac{1}{n+1} (\frac{n+1}{n})^n = \frac{1}{n+1} (1+\frac{1}{n})^n$. Now, $\frac{1}{n+1} \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ and $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n \to e$ as $n \to \infty$. So the product goes to $0 \cdot e =0 $ as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$\frac{(n+1)^{n-1}}{n^n}=\frac{(n+1)^{n-1}(n+1)}{n^n(n+1)}=\frac{(n+1)^n}{n^n(n+1)}=\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n\frac{1}{n+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

LEt

$$ a_n = \frac{(n+1)^{n-1}}{n^n} = \frac{1}{n+1} \left( \frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n$$

Put $b_n = \frac{1}{n+1} $ and

$c_n = \left( \frac{n+1}{n}\right)^n $.

Clearly, $b_n \to 0$ and $c_n \to e$. Hence

$$ \lim a_n = (\lim b_n) ( \lim c_n ) = 0 \times e = 0$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{(n+1)^{n-1}}{n^n}=\frac{(n+1)^{n-1}}{n^{n-1}n}=\left(1+\frac{1}{n} \right)^{n-1}\frac{1}{n}=\left(1+\frac{1}{n} \right)^{n\frac{n-1}{n}}\frac{1}{n} \longrightarrow e^1\cdot 0=0 $$
when $n\rightarrow \infty$.